# Ist ein Wohnmobil immer ein Auto?

Tags: noun, meaning

Ist ein Wohnmobil immer auch ein Auto, oder kann es auch ein anfügbarer Wagen sein?

[image: Wohnmobil?]

Comment: Das Bild stellt also *kein* Wohnmobil dar.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unter einem *Wohnmobil* versteht man ein Kraftfahrzeug (oder Automobil, kurz Auto) bei dem die Einrichtung fest mit dem Fahrzeug verbaut ist und das sich von selbst fortbewegen kann.

Sobald es sich um einen Anhänger handelt, spricht man von einem *Wohnwagen* (der keinen eigenen Antrieb besitzt, sondern ein Zugfahrzeug benötigt).

Deshalb ist ein Wohnwagen (wie im Bild der Frage zu sehen) kein Wohn- oder Automobil.

Comment: Ich würde ein Wohnmobil aber nicht als Auto bezeichnen…

Comment: deshalb auch Kraftfahrzeug ;)

Comment: Da "Auto" die Kurzform von "Automobil" ist, kann man strenggenommen auch bei einem Wohnmobil von "Auto" sprechen.

Comment: Okay, anders: Ich würde ein Wohnmobil nicht als Automobil bezeichnen… ;) Under Automobil/Auto verstehe zumindest ich eher etwas in Form eines PKWs.

Comment: Andererseits würde ich einen Wohnmobil (also mit Motor) auch als Wohnwagen bezeichnen können.

Comment: @Peter: Nein, ein Wohnmobil ist kein Wohnwagen und umgekehrt.

Comment: Also für mich ist "Auto" nicht 100% gleichbedeutend mit "Automobil", auch wenn das natürlich klar die Wortherkunft ist. Nach meinem Bauchgefühl bedeutet "Auto" = PKW und "Automobil" = KFZ. Ein Wohnmobil wäre also durchaus ein Automobil - aber kein Auto. Würdet Ihr einen LKW als Auto bezeichnen?

Comment: Die Diskussion erinnert mich wieder an den alten Witz, wo jemand seine Freundin das erste Mal in seinem neuen Porsche mitnimmt, und an einer Kreuzung fragt: "Kommt von rechts ein Auto?", und sie antwortet: "Nein ..." – er gibt Gas – "... nur so ein blöder Laster!"

Answer (score 4):

*Auto* ist eine Abkürzung von *Automobil*, einem Wort, das aus dem griechischen **αὐτό** (selbst) und dem lateinischen **mobilis** (beweglich) abgeleitet ist.

Ein angefügter Wagen bewegt sich nicht von alleine, ist also kein Auto. Ein Wohnmobil hingegen besitzt aber immer einen Motor. Das Fahrzeug auf dem Bild in der Frage, das nicht alleine fahren kann, nennt man übrigens "**Wohnwagen**."

Comment: Ein Wohnmobil ist doch nur **wohn** und **mobilis**, nicht **αὐτό**.

Comment: @Tim Ich habe "Automobil" geschrieben.

Comment: @splattne: I agree that a detachable trailer is not an _Automobil_. Are you making an etymological argument that that premise implies "Ein Wohnmobil besitzt also immer einen Motor"? If so, I can't follow it. (I'd agree if it were called _Wohnautomobil_.)

Comment: *Automobil* - αὐτό-mobilis - "selbstbeweglich". *Wohnmobil* - wohn-mobilis - "bewegbare Wohnung". Ein *Wohnwagen* (Anhänger) scheint auf diese Beschreibung zu passen. Ergo kann ein Anhänger ein Wohnmobil sein. Oder hab ich was falsch verstanden? ;-P

Comment: Vielleicht habe ich mich etwas umständlich ausgedrückt. Die eigentliche Frage war ja, ob ein Wohnwagen auch ein Wohnmobil ist. Da ein Wohnwagen sich nicht selbst bewegen kann, ist es auch kein Wohnmobil.

Comment: Entscheidend ist hier glaube ich, dass das "-mobil" in Wohnmobil nicht einfach nur von "Automobil" abstammt sondern hier implizit als Verkürzung davon anzusehen ist (zum Zweck der Wortbildung). Das sieht man ja an den ganzen Antworten und Kommentaren hier, die sich mit ihren Begründungen, warum ein Wohnwagen kein Wohnmobil ist, alle auf den eigentlich ja gar nicht vorhandenen "auto"-Teil beziehen, so als wäre ihnen gar nicht bewusst, dass er fehlt...

Answer (score 3):

Ein Wohnmobil kann aus eigener Kraft fahren (ist also im weitesten Sinne ein Auto), ein Wohnwagen ist lediglich ein bewohnbarer Anhänger.

Answer (score 3):

Laut Anlage XXIX zu § 20 Absatz 3a Satz 4 der deutschen Straßenverkehrs-Zulassungs-Ordnung (StVZO) ist ein Wohnmobil ein

> Fahrzeug der Klasse M mit besonderer Zweckbestimmung, das so konstruiert ist, dass es die Unterbringung von Personen erlaubt und mindestens die folgende Ausrüstung umfasst:
>   a) Tisch und Sitzgelegenheiten,
>   b) Schlafgelegenheiten, die u. U. tagsüber als Sitze dienen können,
>   c) Kochgelegenheit und
>   d) Einrichtungen zur Unterbringung von Gepäck und sonstigen Gegenständen.
>   Diese Ausrüstungsgegenstände sind im Wohnbereich fest anzubringen, mit Ausnahme des Tischs, der leicht entfernbar sein kann.

Fahrzeuge der Klasse M sind:

> Für die Personenbeförderung ausgelegte und gebaute Kraftfahrzeuge mit mindestens vier Rädern.